# NGINX Only pass requests coming from main domain

Tags: node.js, nginx, server

My current NGInx setup is such that it takes all requests from Http and redirects them to HTTPS and then it passes the request to my Node server running on Unbutu localhost.

My quest is, how do I make it so it only accepts requests coming from my app.domain.com (which is hosted somewhere else) and my api.domain.com which is hosted on my Ubuntu cloud. So if you visit api.domain.com you will never get passed to the Node server or if you send a request from anywhere else than app.domain.com you will also never get passed to the Node server.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name api.maindomain.com;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.maindomain.com/xxxx.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.maindomain.com/xxx.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:xxxx/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on the situation you are trying to protect against.  You would use referrers and an IP white list.  This would ensure that the system sending you the request is from the source system, then check to make sure its from the source domain.  However, IP restriction is strict and sometime overkill for web applications and things like referrer can be spoofed.  So -- what is the need/intention for the ask?

Comment: Well for now I know that all requests going to my api should come from my app domain. I use jwt in node but I thought I could filter some of the requests before even passing them to the server for extra security or to remove processing from the node server or something. But if it is useless I should filter things to maximum directly in my node server ?

Comment: If your app domain IP is static, you can use `allow` and `deny` directives from [ngx_http_access_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) (see configuration example, it is quite simple). In addition nginx has a [ngx_http_auth_jwt_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_jwt_module.html) (but I never use it, so can't help you here).